# HOW TO FETCH MMM-YYYY format in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

how do i fetch mmm-yyyy format in sql (eg : Dec - 2020)

please help me in this regard

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Ideally this is something for your presentation layer. Have SQL return the date as it is, a date and time data type, and then have the presentation layer change it to the `MMM-yyyy` format.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is just to construct the values:

```
select concat(left(datepart(monthname, col, 3), ' - ', year(col))
```

Or just using `format()`:

```
select format(col, 'MMM - yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'MMM-yyyy') as date
```

[test picture in my environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwSHh.jpg)

Comment: Adding an explanation will be help to understand better.